# Architecting our solution and advice

Tags: .net, architecture, tfs

my organisation has a .NET solution (C# MVC) and we are struggling a little with attempting to keep our solution reusable but at the same time extensible.

We have a have 4 clients

A, B, C, D

Each of these clients require a website and each website is very very similar say 90% similar. Therefore we have created a base template which includes a data layer, core, services and web layer (including controllers/helpers/mapping/validation). All clients will consume this template. The only parts where the clients will not be sharing code will be markup and a theme which will be applied to that client. Even scripts/base css will be shared between clients.

This has been working for about 7 months relatively well, until now.

Clients A and B have been deployed and in production.

We are currently working on Client C, and Client D is yet to be implemented.

While working on client C, clients A and B also require bug fixing/feature changes etc. However because we are working on client C the template is not always "production ready" and therefore code will be released for clients A and B with untested code. We have now been resorting to implement the majority of the features directly in client C to avoid making changes to the template.

Of course a simple option would be to branch and work on the branch, but because we are forced to use TFS this makes it difficult. Most likely we will just branch and work from there but is there any additional advice (sources of info) to read up on about how others fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience branching is the best way to make the customer solutions more independent from each other. Plus, you can decide when to incorporate changes into a customer solution and are not forced to release code that is not production ready along with a bugfix for a customer.

The straight forward approach is to have all the projects in a solution and create a branch for each customer that contains the complete solution in source code. This way you can make customer specific changes to the complete code. Your source tree would look similar to this:

- Branch1

  - Solution

    - Project 1
    - Project 2
- Branch2

  - Solution

    - Project 1
    - Project 2

If you want to introduce a greater separation between shared base components and customer specific code, you might think about creating a separate solution for the base components and have the customer specific solutions and projects reference the binaries. While ensuring that changes in the base components (sooner or later) are incorporated into customer projects in the same way, this is a lot more complicated and requires a significant amount of effort. Also you are less flexible as you cannot make customer specific changes to the base components. I'd recommend this only if you expect a lot of customer Projects because then it pays off that you have a tested set of base components that are the same for all customers.
Your solution tree would look something like this:

- Base Components root Folder

  - Base components branch

    - Solution

      - Projects
- Base Components Binary Output (maybe in a common area of your source control)
- Customer Solutions root Folder

  - Branch 1

    - Base components Folder (branched from base components binary Output, merge if you want to use a new Version of the components for a customer)
    - Solution

      - Projects
  - Branch ...

Of course you can mix both approaches (the described ones are the extremes). I hope this helps.